# If and Else comparing numbers JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am new to JavaScript... The following code displays *correct* even when I submit an incorrect value, I can't get the "else" section to work:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA [*/
    function myFunction() {
        var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
        if (answer = 10)
          document.getElementById("valid").innerHTML = "Correct!";
        else
          document.getElementById("valid").innerHTML = "Please, Try Again!";
      }
      /* ]]> */
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>What is 3+7=?</h2>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="answer">
    <input type="submit" onClick="myFunction(); return false;">
  </form>
  <div id="valid"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `=` Makes an assignment. You want to compare, which would be `==`. `if (answer == 10)`. To add to that, `answer` is just a DOM element, you need to get its value.

Comment: Change if (answer = 10) to if (answer == 10)

Comment: You also need to access the value of the answer element `document.getElementById('answer').value`

Comment: First of all, as others noted equality comparison is ==, = is assignment. 
Secondly, if you have a lot of specific cases (such as ==10, ==11, ==N...), you might use 'switch' statement. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Also, if programming is new to you, you'd benefit from a structured approach, rather than hacking stuff together. A solid book (I'm no JS expert, so I can't really recommend anything specific here) will be invaluable. Also http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your function to

```
function myFunction() {
    var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById('answer').value,10);
    if (answer === 10)
        document.getElementById("valid").innerHTML = "Correct!";
    else
        document.getElementById("valid").innerHTML = "Please, Try Again!";
}
```

And it will work like a charm.

Explanation.

The element with `id="answer"` is an input. To retrieve value of an input, you need `.value`

Like `var answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;`

Now, this will return the value in your `input type="text"` as a string.

Ideally, you should parse it into the `int` using `parseInt()`.

Like `var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById('answer').value);`

This will avoid type coersion.

Lastly, you want to `compare` the two values, so you need to use `==` operator.
Single `=`, an assignment operator would just assign the value and would always result into true since assignment gets successful.

And it's best practice to use strict comparison with datatypes. using `===` operator.

Comment: this answer is more correct because it prevents type coercion.

Comment: don't forget the _radix_ argument to `parseInt()`.

Comment: @Barmar I was recently working on a project where a fellow developer didn't pay attention to jsHint and did not provide a radix argument.  He was trying to parse sections of a date (11-01-2011) and found out that it is essential to add that radix!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the equality operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`.

Also you need to get the value of the answer, not the just the element.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA [*/
    function myFunction() {
        var answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
        if (answer == 10)
          document.getElementById("valid").innerHTML = "Correct!";
        else
          document.getElementById("valid").innerHTML = "Please, Try Again!";
      }
      /* ]]> */
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>What is 3+7=?</h2>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="answer">
    <input type="submit" onClick="myFunction(); return false;">
  </form>
  <div id="valid"></div>
</body>

</html>
```